# Landau's derivation of a free particle's kinetic energy- expansion of a function?

Tags: classical-mechanics, calculus

I was reading a bit of Landau and Lifshitz's Mechanics the other day and ran into the following part, where the authors are about to derive the kinetic energy of a free particle. They use the fact that the Lagrangian of this particle must be the same (or at most, differ by the total time derivative of a function of co-ordinates and time) in different inertial frames.

> *We have $L'=L(v'^2)=L(v^2+2\mathbf{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{\epsilon}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^2)$. Expanding this expression in powers of $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ and neglecting terms above the first order, we obtain* 
>   $$L(v'^2)=L(v^2)+\frac{\partial L(v^2)}{\partial (v^2)}2\mathbf{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{\epsilon}.$$

I think I'm ok with all the physics in this section. What I don't get is just the part I quoted above (so maybe this post is better suited for the math site, but since this is book is so physics-y I thought I'd post it here). My math is pretty rusty, so I'm not really sure- how do the authors expand the function to arrive at the above expression? It reminds me a bit of a Taylor expansion, but not very much. What's the process used to arrive at it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Taylor expansion.  You might be a little freaked out because they are treating $L$ as a function of $v^2$, but that doesn't matter, consider

$$ L(x + \delta) \sim L(x) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \delta + O(\delta^2) $$

but take $x=v^2$ and $\delta = 2 \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{\epsilon} + \epsilon^2 $,

$$
\begin{align*}
 L(v'^2) &= L( v^2 + 2 \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{\epsilon} + \epsilon^2) \\
   &\sim L(v^2) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2} ( 2 \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{\epsilon} + \epsilon^2) + O(\epsilon^2) \\
 &\sim L(v^2) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2}  2 \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{\epsilon}  + O(\epsilon^2) 
\end{align*}
$$

We can drop the other $\epsilon^2 \frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2}$ term since we are only interested in terms of first order.

#### Taylor Expansion Generally

If its the taylor expansion you're having trouble with, that's pretty easy to show as well.  Consider $f(x + \epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ small, we might want to express the value of $f(x + \epsilon)$ as a power series in $\epsilon$, so we look for something of the form

$$ f(x + \epsilon) = a_0 + a_1  \epsilon + a_2 \epsilon^2 + \cdots $$

How do we determine the coefficients, well we can find $a_0$ by taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, obtaining
$$ f(x) = a_0 $$

Great, but how would we get the $a_1$ coefficient?  Well, just take a derivative of both sides

$$ f'(x + \epsilon) = a_1 + 2 a_2 \epsilon + \cdots $$

and just take the limit again, obtaining
$$ f'(x) = a_1 $$

Doing that process once more you get
$$ f''(x) = 2 a_2 $$

So, so far we've got

$$ f(x + \epsilon) = f(x) + f'(x) \epsilon + \frac 12 f''(x) \epsilon^2 + \cdots $$

If you think generally, you should be able to convince yourself that in general, for the $n$th term, we'll have

$$ f^{(n)}(x) = n! a_n $$

giving us the general Taylor series result

$$ f(x + \epsilon) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(x) \epsilon^n $$

Comment: Ah, perfect- thanks. One more doubt I just had- why are they only interested in first order terms? Is it because $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small? It seems to me like if that was the reason, there would be some loss of generality in the derivation.

Comment: @PhysicsLlama They may have glossed this a bit in the text, but they use this first order difference to argue that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2}$ is independent of $v^2$.  But if the first partial is independent (meaning a constant) any higher partials must vanish, meaning even if we tried to go to higher order in the expansion, they would all disappear.

Comment: @PhysicsLlama also the argument must work for vanishing $\epsilon$ as you point out.

Comment: Neat way to remember the coefficients of a Taylor expansion there, by the way :) +1.

Comment: Important subtlety that I just noticed: you expanded f(x+e) in powers of e, and then took the derivative of the polynomial with respect to e in order to find the coefficients a. So you didn't take the derivative of f with respect to x, but rather with respect to e. In your earlier development, though, you took it with respect to v^2, which you had set as your x. Isn't this inconsistent?

Comment: @PhysicsLlama To fix the second thing, and I should have made it clear, but take the derivative of both sides with respect to $z = x + \epsilon$, that fixes it.  For both the top and bottom part, the point is to take the derivative of the function with respect to its own argument.