Why must the total time derivative only be a linear function of velocity?
I'm hung up on page 7 of Landau & Lifshitz Course on Mechanics. They claim,

$$L(v'^2) = L(v^2)+\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2}2\textbf v\cdot \epsilon \tag{p.7}$$
The second term on the right of this equation is a total time derivative only if it is a linear function of the velocity $\textbf v$.

I can understand the Taylor expansion to get to this equation, but I do not understand why this must be a linear function of $\textbf v$.
If I understand correctly, we need to find a function$f(q, t)$ such that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(f(q,t)) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2}2\textbf v\cdot \epsilon$$
If $f(q,t) = q^2$, would the total time derivative not include a nonlinear function of $\textbf v$? Is there some restriction imposed upon $f$ such that it must also be a linear function of $q$?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128139/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/288895/2451 and links therein.

The Taylor expansion is:
$f(x+\delta)=f(x)+f'(x)\delta+...$
Here $x=v^2$, and you know that
$v^2+\delta=(\vec{v}+\vec{\epsilon})^2=v^2+2\vec{v}.\vec{\epsilon}+\epsilon^2$
thus,
$\delta=2\vec{v}.\vec{\epsilon}+\epsilon^2$
discarding terms of order $\epsilon^2$, then you get the expression in the book.

It comes down to how the differentiation works. The function I mentioned, $f(q, t)=q^2$ would indeed be a linear function once differentiated:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(q^2)=\frac{d}{dt}(q\cdot q)$$
Which, when used with the product rule, would be:
$$\frac{dq}{dt} \cdot q + q \frac{dq}{dt}= 2q\cdot v$$
Where $v$ only appears in its first order still. It turns out that for higher degrees, i.e. $ f=q^n$, the solution would be:
$$n \cdot q(t)^{n-1}\cdot v$$
So, regardless of how you look at it, the function must be a linear function of $v$.
